# How to select div which was clicked by user from jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete and upon selection of any item, I add a new div with class set to `active_chat` so this div becomes active. Before adding new div, I remove `active_chat` from previous divs so only the last added div remains active.

Now I want to give option to users to click any other non-active div and make it active i.e. set its class `active_chat`. For that I am looking for code to select div which was clicked by user but I don't know how to do that as my code gives all divs and I don't actually know which one was clicked by the user.

Following is my main div which contain all elements

```
<div class="inbox_chat" id="inboxchat">                        
</div>
```

Following is jquery I am using to add new div dynamically and setting its class to `active_chat`

```
$("#users").autocomplete
({
    select: function (event, ui)
    {
        $('.chat_list').removeClass("active_chat");
        $('#inboxchat').prepend('<div class="chat_list active_chat"><div class= "chat_people"><div class="chat_img"> <img src="mypic.jpg" alt="sometitle"></div><div class="chat_ib"><h5>my name<span class="chat_date">Dec 25</span></h5><p>sometext</p></div></div></div>');
    }
});
```

Following is the code I am using to select current div which was clicked by the user but it is picking all divs

```
$(document).on('click', '#inboxchat', function () {
    var clicked = $(this).siblings();
    console.log(clicked);
    alert("now1");
});
```

When a user clicks any div, I simply want to set `active_chat` for that div and remove this class from other divs.

**EDIT**
I am setting `active_chat` for a div called `chat_list`

Comment: put click listener on class chat_list. In the event listener "this" will point the the div clicked and you can directly access and manage that on DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if you want it want it to work on any div on the page:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
    $("div").removeClass("active_chat");
    $(this).addClass("active_chat");
});
```

Does this have to work only for divs with class "inbox_chat"? If so, try:

```
$('div. inbox_chat').on('click', function(){
    $("div").removeClass("active_chat");
    $(this).addClass("active_chat");
});
```

Comment: I am setting `active_chat` for a div called `chat_list`. Have edited my OP.